# A question on self-dual differential 2-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

This question is from Lemma 2 in Derdzinski's [paper](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1983__49_3/CM_1983__49_3_405_0/CM_1983__49_3_405_0.pdf).

Let $$\omega=e_1\wedge e_2+e_3\wedge e_4, \eta=e_1\wedge e_3+e_4\wedge e_2, \theta=e_1\wedge e_4+e_2\wedge e_3$$
be a basis for self-dual two-forms on a four-manifold, where $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ is an orthonormal basis of the tangent space. Derdzinski said that

$$\omega^2=\eta^2=\theta^2=-id,\ \omega\eta=\theta=-\eta\omega.$$

I was wondering what $\omega^2=-id$ and $\omega\eta=\theta$ mean? Is this wedge product or other operation? Thank you very much.

Comment: I suspect that (a) it's exterior product, and (b) the second equation should have a 0 where you have a $\theta$.

Comment: Derdzinski said from the formulas, the tangent space has a quaternionic structure, so it is $\theta$.

Comment: OK. In that case it certainly can't be wedge product, because a 2-form isn't likely to equal a 4-form. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to interpreting these formulas is the isomorphism Derdzinski mentions in part (b) of Lemma 2: 
$$
\Lambda^2 T_xM \cong \mathfrak s \mathfrak o(4).
$$
Note that $\Lambda^2 T_xM$ refers to the space of *$2$-vectors* (alternating contravariant $2$-tensors), not $2$-forms (which would be denoted $\Lambda^2 T_x^*M$ in his notation).

What this isomorphism means is that a $2$-vector can be canonically interpreted as a skew-symmetric endomorphism of the tangent space. The endomorphism corresponding to a $2$-vector $\omega$ is the $(1,1)$-tensor $\omega^\sharp$ obtained by raising one index of $\omega$. That $\omega^\sharp$ is skew-symmetric is easiest to see in an orthonormal basis, where the matrix of $\omega^\sharp$ is either same as that of $\omega$ or its negative (depending on which index is raised).

Using this canonical isomorphism, the products that Derdzinski writes are compositions of endomorphisms.  You can check this by writing the matrices of $\omega,\eta,\theta$ in terms of the basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_4\}$ and computing their matrix products. (You'll have to figure out which is the correct index to raise in order to get the signs right in these products.)

Comment: Sorry, Aren't bi-vectors and 2-forms in 1-1 correspondence? I

Comment: @C.F.G: Well, yes. But just having a 1-1 correspondence is not useful. (For example, there's a [1-1 correspondence](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24932/6751) between the real line and the set of all homeomorphism classes of connected manifolds.) In fact, on every smooth manifold, there's a bundle isomorphism between the bundle of bivectors and the bundle of $2$-forms, but that's not useful either because the isomorphism depends on a lot of choices. However, on a Riemannian manifold, as is the case here, they are **_canonically_** isomorphic to each other and to the bundle of skew endomorphisms.

Comment: Even though they're canonically isomorphic, they're different kinds of objects, and it's important to be clear which one you're talking about in any given setting.

Comment: Ok, I asked this because I have seen many times in papers that authors claim that (if I am not mistaken) curvature operator can be seen as operator on $\Lambda^2 T_pM$ as well as $\Lambda^2 T_p^*M$.

Comment: Ohh, sorry. Your answer and comment confused me for 4 hours. You meant that it is not true $\Lambda^2 T_x^*M \cong \mathfrak s \mathfrak o(4)$?

Comment: On a Riemannian manifold, there's a canonical isomorphism between $\Lambda^2 T_x^*M$ and $\Lambda^2 T_x M$, and using this canonical isomorphism, the curvature tensor determines operators on both $\Lambda^2 T_xM$ and $\Lambda^2 T_x^*M$. It's also true that $\Lambda^2 T_x^*M$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak s \mathfrak o(4)$, but this isomorphism is _**not**_ canonical -- it depends on a choice of basis.

Comment: Is it really important here that this isomorphism to be canonical or not?